# Getting Blank Page when using $wpdb in Wordpress Template

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am Trying to create a Wordpress template with custom php code which connects custom table in Wordpress database, But its showing a blank page for this code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: JNTU
*/
?>

<?php
function doSomething() {
global $wpdb;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
// Not logged in.
} else {
$id = $_POST['ID'];

 $add = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT SUM(tech) AS tech4 FROM (
(SELECT SUM(tm) AS tech FROM jbit WHERE id = :id)
UNION ALL
(SELECT SUM(tm) AS tech FROM hmm WHERE id = :id))t1");
$add -> execute(array(':id'=>$id));
echo " <center><table id='mytable' cellspacing='0'  border=3 align=center> 
<tr><TH scope='col'>Total Marks</TH> </tr><center>"; 
while ($row1 = $add->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 echo "<tr>"; 
 echo "<td align=center>" . $row1['tech4']. "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
  }
}
}
?>
```

Any Idea???

Comment: Try enabling display_errors in your php configuration of check the server logs. a blank page mostly means that an error occured but due to your servers configuration is not printed

Comment: I Have enabled but still its showing blank page, i could find any error message

Comment: Check in your server for an `error_logs` text file.
Anyway , 1) Does your script calls the function? 2)If a user is not logged in - what will he see? 3)use `is_wp_error` as used at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error for better debugging.

Comment: The $wpdb->prepare method does NOT yield an object. Only a prepared SQL string. You're trying to call an execute method on that string, which is resulting in your error.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how `$wpdb->prepare` works. `$wpdb->prepare` takes a string and returns a string. And there is not execute method in the `$wpdb` class. [Check the Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) What you want is:

```
$wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare("SELECT SUM(tech) AS tech4 FROM (
      (SELECT SUM(tm) AS tech FROM jbit WHERE id = %d)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT SUM(tm) AS tech FROM hmm WHERE id = %d)
    )",$id,$id)
);
```

Basically it is [`printf` syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) but without the 'value numbering/value swapping' parts-- ie, this type of thing--`%2$s`. `$wpdb->prepare` is useful but not great because of that.